# why is in Vuejs the toggle functionality not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, toggle

m pulling the last strand of ny hair working onto toggle functionality using vuejs the console i dont find anything
my code seems to be

```
   <template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="nav flex-column sideBar" v-show='isOpen'>
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <nav>
            <div class="content">
                <div  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click='toggleSideBar'>
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </nav>    
   </div>  
   </div>
   </template>

  <script>
   export default{
    data(){
        isOpen=false;
    },
    method(){
        toggleSideBar();
    },
    toggleSideBar(){
        console.log("==========="+this.isOpen)
            this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
        }
   }
  </script>
```

button on click the togglle fuctionality doesnt work out doent work out
any help much appreciated

this is the inspect html in browser

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
```

and not

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='toggleSidebar()'>
```

the click function not added to it

m using sass

```
               .wrapper {
    display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
 width:100%;
   }
 .sideBar{
 border: 1px solid;
width: 30%;
height: 100vh;
margin-left: 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
background-color: #f9f9f7;
   }
 .container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px; 
      padding-left: 0px; 
   }
     .navbar{
      @extend .navbar;
   background-color: #eae9e5;
    }
     .sidebar.active {
     margin-left: -250px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, add `return` then change `=` to `:` and `;` to `,` in your `data()`

```
data(){
    return{
        isOpen: false,
    }
},
```

then put the `toggleSideBar()` inside your `method` like this:

```
methods:{
    toggleSideBar(){
        console.log("================"+this.isOpen)
        this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
    }
}
```

**FINAL OUTPUT**

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            isOpen: false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        toggleSideBar(){
            console.log("================"+this.isOpen)
            this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. what does the console look like?

Comment: blank no error  buthen y is <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> n not <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='toggleSidebar()'>

Comment: it's because `@click` is a function in **vuejs** it's not html. it should work even though it is not in the inspect element.

Comment: okay but then the entire code seems to be perfect the y is the toogle yet not working

Comment: work cheers;) the return part i had not written   can u plz explain abut the data return

Comment: can u plz explain abut the data return i have no idea about it?

Comment: `data()` initializes the parameters you are going to use. `return` should be included by default to throw the parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182132/discussion-between-tested-and-capt-teemo).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
   export default{
    data(){
        isOpen: false;    //Change this line to : instead of =
    },
    method(){
        toggleSideBar: function(){
        console.log("================"+this.isOpen)
            this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
        }
    },
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: doesnt work on click fuction is not added to the button

Comment: @Tested Well the error is not in the code you provided because we both posted working solutions so maybe tell us what the error says if you get one?

Comment: it doesnt show up any errors compiled suceefully toggle seems to not to be working